# Downloading GitHub Archive files using wget: has {} for iteration

Tags: command-line, bash, wget

If I copy/paste this in the command line, I can download ALL GitHub archive files for 24 hours on January 1st 2015:

```
wget http://data.gharchive.org/2015-01-01-{0..23}.json.gz
```

I want to be able to do this for multiple days, using a script. For example, in my .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    wget $line
  done < download_github_files.txt
```

And in `download_github_files.txt`, I have:

```
http://data.gharchive.org/2015-01-01-{0..23}.json.gz
http://data.gharchive.org/2015-01-02-{0..23}.json.gz
http://data.gharchive.org/2015-01-03-{0..23}.json.gz
```

Unfortunately, when I run the .sh file, I get three printouts of:

```
--2019-02-27 19:00:28--  http://data.gharchive.org/2015-01-01-'%7B'0..23'%7D'.json.gz
Resolving data.gharchive.org (data.gharchive.org)... 
Connecting to data.gharchive.org (data.gharchive.org)...
connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-02-27 19:00:28 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

The problem is clearly with `{`. Escaping that character doesn't help, because it's meant to be an iterator from what I can tell.

How can I download these files using `wget`?

EDIT:

Hmm. I'm having the same issue, trying to use the first posted solution:

.sh file (clearly I'm going to do all months of the year, but I've limited to February for ease of visualization):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {01..12}; do
    if [ ${i} = 02 ]; then
        for j in {01..28}; do
            for k in {0..23}; do
                wget http://data.gharchive.org/2011-${i}-${j}-${k}.json.gz
            done
        done
    fi
done
```

Same problem. For example, I get:

```
--2019-02-27 20:50:05--  http://data.gharchive.org/2011-02-01-5.json.gz
Resolving data.gharchive.org (data.gharchive.org)... 
Connecting to data.gharchive.org (data.gharchive.org)...
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-02-27 20:50:05 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

But if I run the command

```
wget http://data.gharchive.org/2011-02-01-5.json.gz
```

then I have no issue. I can download the file manually, but I can't do it in a bash script. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the `wget` in an `for` iterator loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..23}; do
  wget http://data.gharchive.org/2015-01-01-${i}.json.gz;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Brace expansion happens before variable expansion, so the braces assigned to `$line` aren't expanded.

This should work:

```
eval wget $line
```

where `eval` evaluates the line again. At this point `$line` is already expanded and the shell evaluates a line that looks like your first command:

> ```
> wget http://data.gharchive.org/2015-01-01-{0..23}.json.gz
> ```

---

But **beware!** An entry like

```
foo; rm -rf /some/precious/directory
```

in the `download_github_files.txt` file will result in the following line being *evaluated*:

```
wget foo; rm -rf /some/precious/directory
```

"Evaluated" means `;` does separate commands (while without `eval` this `;` coming from `$line` would be just a part of `foo;` argument passed to `wget`).

See [*Why should `eval` be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/10765659) I doubt this link contains anything you could easily use instead `eval` in this *particular* case, still it sheds light on some general issues. Use `eval` only if the file contains lines under your full control and you're sure they will be evaluated without surprises.